# Trying to combine CSS gradient and background image

Tags: css, background, gradient

I want to have transparent gradient over an image, so I did the following but it shows only the image

```
background-image: url(../img/hex-pattern.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), color-stop(8%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(92%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)));
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify your image first, that image gets drawn on top of the gradient, obscuring it completely. You need to switch them around so the gradient is layered on top (see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering)):

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), color-stop(8%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(92%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2))), url(../img/hex-pattern.png);
```

Don't forget to include the rest of the gradient prefixes and the unprefixed one as well. Although when you do, this means duplicating the `url()` part of your `background-image` declaration as well.

Answer (score 2):

The order (think z-index) of the backgrounds is exactly backwards from what is logical. The first background you set is the one on top:

http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

It's caused me similar frustrations. Just think of it vertically, like on the link:

```
body {
    background:
        background1, <-top
        background2,
        background3; <-bottom
}
```